# I am missing some URL when i am crawling website using nutch crawling

Tags: solr, nutch

I am using nutch to crawl some website for my project but i am loosing lot of data. when i am giving seed URL to nutch for crawling after crawling When i am looking at my crawled data i am observing that i am missing some URLs.
Though i have gave number of round 5 before crawling but after that also it is missing URL which are at round 2. Can any one help me how to solve this problem. as i am new to nutch and need this help. I want to take whole docs in till round 5.
I have searched about it on google and nutch but there was not any solution regarding this.
Can anyone help me with this please.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Have a look at the log files including the "hadoop.log" and search for the missing URLs. Also useful to find the reason: [bin/nutch readdb](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=122916809) and [parsechecker](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=122916848). There are too many potential reasons - URL filters, robots.txt exclusions, incorrectly parsed, "robots noindex", etc. Without context it's impossible to tell why.

Comment: Yes, I got the reason after observing my data. Nutch is not crawling content from web page i am getting many files with content size 0. Because of this it is unable to crawl any URL which is dependent on that web page because it is not extracting any data. any solution for this??

Comment: This looks like the crawled site is running some anti-bot protection which makes the server return empty responses after some time: configure Nutch to be more polite, esp. in case the defaults were changed to crawl faster. Ev., you'll also need to modify or even rotate the HTTP User-Agent name, both options are configurable. Alternatively, contact the site admin to unblock your crawler.